# Why can't pvresize to the exact space taken from allocated physical extents

Tags: lvm

In a physical volume, I have 32 allocated physical extents, each one of 4194304 bytes (or 4MiB). 32*4194304 is 134217728 (128MiB). When trying to resize to that exact size I get an error. Trying to resize to 129MiB works.

Why it is not possible to resize the PV to the exact amount of allocated physical extents? How do I know properly what is the amount I can resize it to?

```
root@osboxes:/etc/lvm# pvdisplay --unit b
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda4
VG Name               vg1
PV Size               135266304 B  / not usable 1048576 B
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4194304 B
Total PE              32
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          32
PV UUID               4XbCGL-eTnk-KFea-eZs5-MQT4-il6C-OPPVTB

root@osboxes:/etc/lvm# pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 134217728b /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: Requested size 128.00 MiB is less than real size <270.06 GiB. Proceed?  [y/n]: y
  WARNING: /dev/sda4: Pretending size is 262144 not 566349824 sectors.
  /dev/sda4: cannot resize to 31 extents as 32 are allocated.
  0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Comment: Are you trying to use pvresize to grow to the full size of the drive? If so just use `pvresize /dev/sda4` . The only time I use setphysicalvolumesize is to shrink a pv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LVM metadata has to go somewhere. Usually this is 1MiB at the start of the PV.

You can check the start offset of the first physical extent like this:

```
pvs -o +pe_start
```

Add the 1st PE offset to the total size and it should work.

You can also set this value at the time of `vgcreate`, as described in the man page:

```
   --dataalignment Size[k|UNIT]
          Align the start of the data to a multiple of this number.  Also
          specify an appropriate Physical Extent size when creating a VG.
          To see the location of the first Physical Extent of an existing
          PV, use pvs -o +pe_start. In addition, it may be shifted by an
          alignment offset.  See lvm.conf/data_alignment_offset_detection
          and --dataalignmentoffset.

   --dataalignmentoffset Size[k|UNIT]
          Shift the start of the data area by this additional offset.
```

Use these carefully as you can end up with very weird offsets otherwise.